# Use a for loop to pick single digit numbers, and concatenate them together to form a String in java

Tags: java, for-loop

So I have to create three random numbers using the Math.random(); method then use a for loop to output each number by itself and then using a concatenate to make them into a string.  It's for my assignment. I've done everything else. I could do it a different way but it requires a for loop.  I can't use the Random class. I have not learned it in my course, therefore it can't be applied.

```
public class Lottery
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        //declare and initialized variables and objects
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);



        //Identify the repeated steps and use a for loop structure


        for(int i=0; i < 3; i++) 
        {
            double lotto = Math.random(); 
            int lotteryNumberDigit = (int)(lotto*10);

           String lotteryNumberString = Integer.toString(lotteryNumberDigit);

        }



            String firstNumber = lotteryNumberString.substring(0,0);
            String secondNumber = lotteryNumberString.substring(1,1);
            String thirdNumber = lotteryNumberString.substring(2,2);

            String firstTwoWinner = firstNumber + secondNumber;
            String lastTwoWinner = secondNumber + thirdNumber;
            String allNumbersWinner = firstNumber + secondNumber + thirdNumber;

            System.out.println("Please enter your three numbers (e.g. 123): ");

            String userInput = input.next();

             if(userInput.substring(0,2).equals(firstTwoWinner))

        {
            System.out.println("Winner: " + allNumbersWinner );

            System.out.println("Congratulations, the front pair matched.");
        }

        else if (userInput.substring(1,3).equals(lastTwoWinner))
        {
             System.out.println("Winner: " + allNumbersWinner );

             System.out.println("Congratulations, the end pair matched.");
        }

        else if (userInput.equals(allNumbersWinner))
        {
             System.out.println("Winner: " + allNumbersWinner );

             System.out.println("Congratulations, both pairs matched.");
        }

        else
        {
             System.out.println("Winner: " + allNumbersWinner );

             System.out.println("Sorry, no matches. You only had one chance out of 100 to win anyway.");
        }



    }
}
```

I had to take out the arrays because my teacher said it was not expectable until the next chapter.

Comment: Let's back up a second. Can you use a for loop to generate the numbers in the first place? Since you already posted some code, I don't mind asking if you can post the exact assignment description...

Comment: Yeah, here is the assignment here

https://access.desire2learn.com/content/enforced/33909-5312_OFF_13_017.001/educator_apcsa_v9/module05/rtfmod05/5.04_AssignmentInstructionsLotteryOdds.pdf?_&d2lSessionVal=G2OTY5H9OdeL27qZUu7W7njXz

Comment: Look at step 5: "Use a for loop to pick the single digit numbers, and concatenate them together to form a String.' This doesn't say anything about outputing each individual number.

Comment: I changed my code but it's now only giving me 000 instead of different numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply write below to print the 3 digit number.

```
    Random random = new Random();
    for(int i=0; i < 3; i++){
        int randomNumber = random.nextInt(10);
        System.out.print(randomNumber);
    }
        System.out.println();
```

Note: **By using `print` method, you will print the three digits next to each other.**

Alternatively you can do below:

```
    String newConcatNumString = "";
    Random random = new Random();
    for(int i=0; i < 3; i++){
       newConcatNumString  = newConcatNumString +random.nextInt(10);
    }
    System.out.println(newConcatNumString);
```

If you want to get the number from string, you can simply do:

```
    int concatenatedValue = Integer.parseInt(newConcatNumString);
```

**EDIT:**
If you don't want to use `Random` class, do the below(updating first example only. Same can be applied into second as well):

```
    for(int i=0; i < 3; i++){
        int lotteryNumberDigit = (int)(Math.random()*10);
        System.out.print(lotteryNumberDigit);
    }
    System.out.println();
```

**Edit:** for you next problem, define an `int[]` in the beginning and store the values in the array for later use of comparison. Updated code snippet as below:

```
    int[] generatedNumbers = new int[3];
    for(int i=0; i < 3; i++){
        int lotteryNumberDigit = (int)(Math.random()*10);
                    generatedNumbers[i] = lotteryNumberDigit;
        System.out.print(lotteryNumberDigit);
    }
    System.out.println();
```

After the above loop, `generatedNumbers` will contain all three digits as separate entry in the array. Your comparison code can be as below:

```
  System.out.println("Please enter your three numbers, one digit at a time): ");
  for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
    int userInput = input.next();
    if(userInput == generatedNumbers[i]){
        System.out.println("Your digit "+i+" is correct");
    }else{
        System.out.println("Your digit "+i+" is incorrect");
    }
  }
```

**EDIT:**
Please do the comparison as below:

```
    if (userInput.equals(allNumbersWinner)) {
         System.out.println("Winner: " + allNumbersWinner );
         System.out.println("Congratulations, both pairs matched.");
    }else if(userInput.substring(0,2).equals(firstTwoWinner )) {
        System.out.println("Winner: " + allNumbersWinner);
        System.out.println("Congratulations, the front pair matched.");
    }else if (userInput.substring(1,3).equals(lastTwoWinner)) {
         System.out.println("Winner: " + allNumbersWinner );
         System.out.println("Congratulations, the end pair matched.");
    }else {
         System.out.println("Winner: " + allNumbersWinner );
         System.out.println("Sorry, no matches. You only had one chance out of 100 to win anyway.");
    }
```

Comment: [Random class Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html)

Comment: @user1745508 then use a `random` method that you know. If you don't know any, then this code is good for you to learn.

Comment: Try `int lotteryNumberDigit = (int)(lotto*10);` in place of `int lotteryNumberDigit = (int)lotto;`. Since you are getting random between `0 to 1`, your `int` is coming to `0`. **Multiply it by to make your random e.g. 0.3566 to 3.566 and then cast it to int. It will give you, 3**. I updated the answer as well.

Comment: Its array of type `int`. Say you want to store 5 numbers or 10 numbers(same kind of value) then you have two ways. One: you can define 5 or 10 variables e.g. number1, number2..number5...nimber10 or you can define a number array of size 10 e.g. int[] number = int[10]. Now you can refer your variables as number[0], number[1], ..number[4]...number[9]. Handling becomes much easier when you use `loops` e.g. for loop. As you can see, I have referred the variables as `generatedNumbers[i]` where i moves as 0, 1 and 2. This way, you don't need to define several variables and you have better control.

Comment: Yes very much. You can very well do that, but don't forget to convert the `String` into `int` e.g. `generatedNumbers[0] = Integer.parseInt(numberString.substring(0,1));`

Comment: I see your comparison wrong. Before correcting, please let me know, is the user input of 3 digits or two digits?

Comment: Please look at the last(newly added) section in the answer. Also please remove the previous comments from here as this page has much more that advised comments.

Comment: So I had to take away the arrays for my assignment. My teacher said I couldn't do that. I updated the code to what I have now, but I'm not sure how to use what is in the for loop in the rest of the program.

Comment: Update the for loop as below: 
       String lotteryNumberString = ""; 
        for(int i=0; i < 3; i++) {
            double lotto = Math.random(); 
            int lotteryNumberDigit = (int)(lotto*10);
           lotteryNumberString =  lotteryNumberString +lotteryNumberDigit;
        }

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure where your problem is here, you seem to have all the pieces.

You create a `for` loop, create a random number via the `Math.random()` method, and then output it.

If you then convert your `int` to a `String` via the [`Integer.toString(int i)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toString%28int%29) method, you can concatenate them using the `+` operator and output all three of them after the loop.

Comment: https://access.desire2learn.com/content/enforced/33909-5312_OFF_13_017.001/educator_apcsa_v9/module05/rtfmod05/5.04_AssignmentInstructionsLotteryOdds.pdf?_&d2lSessionVal=G2OTY5H9OdeL27qZUu7W7njXz


That's the ACTUAL assignment. Am I just completely reading this wrong?

Comment: @user1745508: It looks like they just want you to generate the 3 digits one at a time for some reason, see YogendraSingh:s answer for how to do that.

Comment: @Keppil I believe they do this because it makes it easier to get the leading zeros.

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at the latest addition to your code (with line numbers for reference):

```
1: double randomNumber1 = Math.random(); 
2: int randomNumber = (int)randomNumber1; 

3: for ( int i = 0 ; i < 3 ; i++) 
   { 
4:    System.out.print(randomNumber); 
   }
```

Let's describe what this does in English:

```
1: Generate a random decimal number
2: Convert the random number to an integer
3: Repeat line 4 three times
5:    Print out the random number
```

Do you see a problem here? How many random numbers are generated? What action is repeated in the for loop? What *should* be repeated?

If you can answer these questions, then you might figure out how to fix it so that you generate three (possibly) *different* numbers.

**p.s.** I also suggest that you keep this for loop and cut out the rest of your code. You originally had many of the right pieces. Now we need to build on this for loop (once you fix it) in order to put those pieces together in the right order.

Comment: I changed the for loop, but it made an infinite loop

Comment: @user1745508 Are you certain that the code you posted here is the same as what you are compiling? I strongly suggest that you remove all code from your program except this for loop that we are working on. I don't see any immediate reason why it is an infinite loop.

Comment: @user1745508 Please edit your question so we can see the current version of your code.